# Nomenclature in elsevier template

Tags: nomenclature

How can I print nomenclatures with different subsection like acronyms, greek letters, subscript etc. in `elsearticle.cls`?

Comment: If you are submitting your paper to an elsevier journal, you should contact the publisher.

Answer (score 0):

Will provide an anwser even if it is old, in case anyone have the same question or a related one:

Don't know if elsevier have a specific way to do this, but you can do this with the package [glossaries](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) in any format normally.

See the documentation, in particular "6  Multiple Glossaries".
In short, it is better to make different glossaries,

```
newglossary[〈glg〉]{〈label〉}{〈gls〉}{〈glo〉}{〈title〉
```

one for each section, and print it

```
\printglossary[type=〈type〉]
```